# Bukkit myInventory change item names

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit

I have made a minecraft bukkit plugin which is a gamemode changer GUI but I can't figure out how to change the block names in the inventory that I opened up. At the moment all they say is Iron_Block, Gold_block ...etc

If anyone could help me that would be very helpful

This is the inventory code bit

```
public static Inventory myInventory = Bukkit.createInventory(null, 9, "GamemodeGUI");

static {
    myInventory.setItem(0, new ItemStack(Material.IRON_BLOCK, 1)); //Survival
    myInventory.setItem(1, new ItemStack(Material.DIAMOND_BLOCK, 1)); //Creative
    myInventory.setItem(2, new ItemStack(Material.GOLD_BLOCK, 1)); //Adventure
    myInventory.setItem(3, new ItemStack(Material.LAPIS_BLOCK, 1)); //Spectator

    myInventory.setItem(8, new ItemStack(Material.STAINED_GLASS, 1)); //Cancel
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create your ItemStack out of the method call by assigning it to a variable:

```
ItemStack iron = new ItemStack(Material.IRON_BLOCK, 1); //Can be added to your static block
```

Customize it to change the name for what you want

```
public static void setItemStackName(ItemStack renamed, String customName) {
    ItemMeta renamedMeta = renamed.getItemMeta();
    renamedMeta.setDisplayName(customName);
    renamed.setItemMeta(renamedMeta);
}
```

To the `ItemMeta` you can also add a **lore**. This is the Item's description

```
renamedMeta.setLore(Arrays.asList("Line 1 lore", "Line 2", "..."));
```

Then add the custom ItemStack to the inventory

```
setItemStackName(iron, "Survival");
inventory.setItem(0, iron);    //Pass your customized ItemStack to the method now
```

Comment: Hey, thanks. Just wondering where would I put the ItemStack iron = new ect.. code? Should it be in the static or outside it?

Comment: It can be in the static block

Comment: Don't forget to accept the answer if it solved your problem!

Comment: I tried it and all it did was rename the first block to Cancel and sets it to Stained Glass

Comment: This doesn't happen on my end, coolio, you might be editting the item in another way